# Writing a terminating atomic increment function

Tags: c++, c, operating-system, atomic, compare-and-swap

If I have the following increment function

```cpp
void increment(atomic_int *v)
{
int temp;
do {
temp = *v;
}
while (temp != compare_and_swap(v, temp, temp+1));
}
```

How do I modify this to make it a terminating atomic increment function

Comment: What do you mean by "terminating" in this context?  This isn't standard terminology that I know of.

Comment: What i mean to say is that there is no guarantee that a thread which invoked this function will terminate. So we need to modify it to make it eventually terminate

Comment: It's hardware-dependent, not all CPU architectures have such capability.  If yours does then C11 `atomic_fetch_add` will probably use it, but on an [LL/SC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load-link/store-conditional) architecture, `atomic_fetch_add` might effectively have an internal compare-and-swap loop whose completion is not necessarily guaranteed.  (Though the machine is hopefully designed to make its completion extremely probable.)

Comment: You haven't included a language tag.  Is this meant to be a question about how to do it in standard C?  Then use the [tag:c] tag, but in that case your current code should be using `atomic_compare_exchange_weak` and the second argument should be `&temp`.  And it returns `_Bool`, not the old value.  If you're looking for a solution in some other language, or with features beyond the C standard, then please explain.

Comment: Let us say it is c or cpp

Comment: Who says that you **can** make this succeed in bounded time while still being lock-free?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get a 100% guarantee of completion in bounded time, unless (in C++) you block all other threads temporarily.

The best you can do is use:

- in C, any of `atomic_fetch_add(v, 1)`, `(*v)++`, `++*v`, `*v += 1`;
- in C++, assuming `v` is `std::atomic<int> *`, any of `v->fetch_add(1)`, `++*v`, `(*v)++`, `*v += 1`.

If the hardware provides a method for an atomic increment with bounded completion, the above functions are likely to use it.

However, some machines do not provide such a feature; on an [LL/SC architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load-link/store-conditional), every atomic read-modify-write may be internally compiled into a loop similar to your compare-exchange.  In this case, if other threads are continuously writing to the object, there may not be any guarantee of eventual completion.  (The hardware will probably have some sort of "fairness" feature that makes infinite starvation unlikely, but this may not be guaranteed.)

The only "forward progress" promise made by the C++20 standard is in [intro.progress], where it says that

> If there is only one thread that is not blocked (3.6) in a standard library function, a lock-free execution
> in that thread shall complete. [Note: Concurrently executing threads may prevent progress of a lock-free
> execution. For example, this situation can occur with load-locked store-conditional implementations.
> This property is sometimes termed obstruction-free. — end note]

> (2.2) — When one or more lock-free executions run concurrently, at least one should complete. [Note: It
> is difficult for some implementations to provide absolute guarantees to this effect, since repeated
> and particularly inopportune interference from other threads may prevent forward progress, e.g., by
> repeatedly stealing a cache line for unrelated purposes between load-locked and store-conditional
> instructions. Implementations should ensure that such effects cannot indefinitely delay progress under
> expected operating conditions, and that such anomalies can therefore safely be ignored by programmers.
> Outside this document, this property is sometimes termed lock-free. — end note]

C currently doesn't have any such guarantees at all, as far as I can tell.